# Finite abelian group with same order elements (Proof Checking)

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Let $G$ and $H$ be finite abelian groups such that for every (positive) integer $n$, $G$ and $H$ have the same number of elements of order $n$. Prove that $G \cong K$.

I have seen some proofs of this on this site, but they were kind of hard to follow, so I came up with this, only using the fundamental theorem:
Let $$G\cong \mathbb Z_{p_1^{r_1}} \times \mathbb Z_{p_2^{r_2}} \times \dots \times Z_{p_n^{r_n}}$$ $$H\cong \mathbb Z_{q_1^{s_1}} \times \mathbb Z_{q_2^{s_2}} \times \dots \times Z_{q_m^{s_m}}$$
be the decompositions of $G$ and $H$ into cyclic groups of prime order power. We can see that $|G|=|H|$ because otherwise, if $H$ had more elements, then it would have more elements of some order. Now:
$$|G|=p_1^{r_1}p_2^{r_2}\dots p_n^{r_n}= q_1^{s_1}q_2^{s_2}\dots q_m^{s_m} = |H|$$
Since the prime factorization of a number is unique, then (reordering):
$$m=n$$ and
$$p_i^{r_i}=q_i^{s_i}$$ for $i=1,2,...,n$. Can anybody tell me if there is something wrong with my approach?

Comment: No...there is no guarantee that the $p_i$, say, are distinct.  For instance, the Klein group of order $4$ and the cyclic group of order $4$ both have $4$ elements, but different decompositions ($Z_2\times Z_2$ vs. $Z_4$).

Comment: These groups do not meet the hypothesis for the problem!

Comment: I didn't say they did.  I am just pointing out that your reasoning is flawed.  Specifically, apply your reasoning with $p_1=p_2=2,r_1=r_2=1$ on the left and $q_1=2,s_1=2$ on the right.

Comment: Note:  I'd think you should be able to repair your argument  and thereby prove what you want, but it might take some effort.  For example, your assumptions certainly imply that the maximal power of $p_i$ that appears in the decomposition of $G$ must equal the maximal power of $p_i$ that appears in $H$.  Thus we can cancel that summand out, suggesting that induction is a good way to go.

Comment: Yes indeed. I see now that $m \neq n$ (possibly). Nevertheless, we are still talking about the same set of primes, son canceling out powers seam reasonable. Thank you very much!